# Power BI - Using Field Parameters in a Slicer, is it possible to filter out returned blank values depending on which field is selected?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've set up a Slicer using the preview feature Field Parameters for the purpose of showing Fields A,B,C,D,etc. (whatever you select) by a certain grouping.

[image: Question/Field 1]

[image: Field Parameters Slicer]

[image: Question/Field 2]

**I would like to filter out blank values regardless of what field is selected**, but by default, filtering out blanks in Field A from the visual also filters out "Field A = blank" when B is selected.

Comment: Can you share a .pbix with dummy sample data to illustrate the issue?